# Different styles for x-axis and y-axis scrollbars of the same <div>

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

Assume I have a div:

`<div class="nav-menu"/>`

And I'm trying to customize CSS style for scrollbar using `::scrollbar` pseudo-element:

```css
.nav-menu::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    background: white;
}
```

But this style applies to both x-axis and y-axis scrollbars. Are there any approaches to set different styles using pure CSS only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think you can style horizontal and vertical scrollbars seperate like this.

Horizontal:

```
.nav-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal  {
    height: 8px;
    background: gray;
}
```

Vertical:

```
.nav-menu::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    width: 8px;
    background: white;
}
```

See here for more details, second section 'The Different States':
https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Comment: Thanks to you, I have found out that there are `:vertical` and `:horizontal` pseudo-classes applied to `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` pseudo-element. I have no idea why it doesn't work in my case, but still that's the answer I was looking for. Pure css, no js, no workarounds.